# Status of CMV Development?

Tags: configurable-map-viewer

I see the last version was 2.0.0-beta.2 on Jul 7, 2017 and wonder, has development been discontinued?

Answer (score 1):

The [development branch](https://github.com/cmv/cmv-app/tree/develop) continues to be updated with features, patches and support for the latest version of the
ArcGIS JavaScript API. That is the default branch in the repository and is the best choice for your applications.